# Grails: Carry forward params on g:actionSubmit is clicked

Tags: grails, gsp

How to carry forward the parameters when `g:actionSubmit` button is clicked?

Here is my `gsp` code:

```
<g:checkBox name="msgCheck" checked="" value="${userInstance.emailId}"></g:checkBox>
...
<g:actionSubmit class="update" action="delete" value="Delete" params="${params}"></g:actionSubmit>
```

Here is my controller code:

```
def delete() {
    try {
        def user_list = params.msgCheck

        //deleting the user
        //successful.

        redirect(action: "list", params: params)
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Deleted Exception---->>" + e.getMessage())
    }
}
```

redirect is missing with `params`. I wanted to carry forward `params` on `redirect`.

The URL before I clicked on 'delete' `g:actionSubmit` button looks like:

```
http://localhost:8080/message/list?offset=10&max=100
```

After 'delete' `g:actionSubmit` button is clicked, the url looks like (and has extra parameters:

```
 http://localhost:8080/message/list?msgCheck=ga12%40user.com&msgCheck=&_action_domainDelete=Delete&_msgCheck=&_msgCheck=&_msgCheck=&_msgCheck=&_msgCheck=&_msgCheck=&_msgCheck=&_msgCheck=&_msgCheck=&_msgCheck=&_msgCheck=&domainId=1&noofrows=100
```

How do I carry forward the parameter when `g:actionSubmit` button is clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that you can pass `params` with `actionSubmit` in this way. You can use `params` attribute of [g:form tag](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Tags/form.html), like

```
<g:form params="${params}">
    ...
</g:form>
```

or

```
<g:form params="[offset: params.offset, max: params.max]">
    ...
</g:form>
```

Comment: Thank you :). As per the link http://osdir.com/ml/lang.groovy.grails.user/2008-06/msg00817.html.   

Adding few lines of code to your answer: The extra parameter should be removed in controller.
             
            params.remove("msgCheck")
            params.remove("_action_domainDelete")
            params.remove("_msgCheck")
            params.remove("domainId")
            params.remove("noofrows")